# Random string generator C#

Tags: c#, string, random, generator

I have made a simple number generator, and I have a question: is it possible for the generator to eject "red", "blue", "green", " yellow" and "white" instead of the numbers 1-5?

```
namespace zufallsgenerator
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        Random r = new Random();

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void btnWhlie_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int summe = 0, z; 

            lblAnzeige.Text = " ";

           while (summe <= 0)
           {
                z = r.Next(1, 6);
                summe = summe + z;
           }
           lblAnzeige.Text += summe + "\n";               
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be easy enough for you to convert it.  When you say you want the generator to eject the color names... how exactly do you want to use the color names?  right now you are summing the numbers and that wouldn't make sense with colors.

Comment: I have to write a program, were you can click on 5 buttons in 5 colors, and on thedsisplay you see "red" written in blue  for example and so you have to press the red button...

Answer (score 11):

You could create a simple array and access it with a randomly generated index, e.g.:

```
var r = new Random();
string[] colors = {"red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "white"};
var random_color = colors[r.Next(colors.Length)];
```

Comment: Can you post the whole code? because it doesn't work for me :( but i think i have make the mistake and your code is right ;)

Comment: @Franz you need to seed your random :)

Answer (score 3):

You could use an [enum](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sbbt4032%28v=vs.90%29.aspx).

Define something  like

```
enum Color
{
   Red,
   Green,
   Blue
}
```

Then you can cast your int to this:

```
Color color = (Color)r.Next(1, 6)
```

And, if you wish

```
Text = color.ToString();
```

Comment: This will fail if the generated number is > 2.

Comment: Don't use an enum for this. It means that you can never use a string which is not a valid C# identifier. If you do use an enum, you should use the `[Description]` attribute to get around this.

Comment: You're right on this. I originally thought that he was really interested to get a random color, not to get the _text_ of the random colors.

Answer (score 2):

If you get output like 1-5 you could create string[] containing 5 elements

`string[] colors = new string[] { "red", "blue", "green", " yellow", "white" }`

And instead of retrieving `r.Next( 1, 6 )` you could retrieve `colors[ r.Next( 0, 5 ) ]` (because string array is 0-indexed, changed the min and max value).

Comment: there i get an error: "Error 1 An implicit conversion from type 'string' to 'int' is not possible." what did i make wrong? maybe you can post the whole code? I'm new in c# :(

Answer (score 1):

Taking Xi Huan's answer, you can make it a bit prettier using an extension method:

```
public static T Next<T>(this System.Random Random, params T[] List)
{
    if(List.Length==0)
        return default(T);
    return List[Random.Next(0, List.Length)];
}
```

Then calling it is just:

```
var r=new System.Random();
var randon_color = r.Next("red", "blue", "green", "yellow", "white");
```

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is create a list of strings. Then put the random number as i. So like
 `List<string> list1 = new List<string>{"red", "blue", "green"};` then use your random number like this to call a random element of it. `list1[randomNumber]`;

Answer (score 0):

Define an array with the posible desired output values and instead of concatenating summe to text, add YourArrayOfNamedValues[summe]